# Should the number of vertexes be equal to the number of texCoords?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader

My vertexShader:

```
attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord;

varying vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * vertexPosition;
    texCoord = vertexTexCoord;
}
```

My fragmentShder:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D texSampler2D;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord);
}
```

Init Shader:

```
 if (shader2D == nil) {
    shader2D = [[Shader2D alloc] init];
    shader2D.shaderProgramID = [ShaderUtils compileShaders:vertexShader2d :fragmentShader2d];
    if (0 < shader2D.shaderProgramID) {
        shader2D.vertexHandle = glGetAttribLocation(shader2D.shaderProgramID, "vertexPosition");
        shader2D.textureCoordHandle = glGetAttribLocation(shader2D.shaderProgramID, "vertexTexCoord");
        shader2D.mvpMatrixHandle = glGetUniformLocation(shader2D.shaderProgramID, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
        shader2D.texSampler2DHandle  = glGetUniformLocation(shader2D.shaderProgramID,"texSampler2D");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Could not initialise shader2D");
    }
}
return shader2D;
```

Rendering:

```
GLKMatrix4 mvpMatrix;
mvpMatrix = [self position: position];
mvpMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply([QCARutils getInstance].projectionMatrix, mvpMatrix);
glUseProgram(shader.shaderProgramID);
glVertexAttribPointer(shader.vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(shader.textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)texCoords);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.vertexHandle);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader.textureCoordHandle);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture textureID]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&mvpMatrix);
glUniform1i(shader.texSampler2DHandle, 0);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)indices);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.vertexHandle);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(shader.textureCoordHandle);
```

It seems to work properly when one texture coordinates corresponds to one and only one vertex coordinates(Number of `texCoords` == Number of `vertices`)

My question: Does openGL assign a texture coordinates to one and only one vertex? In other words, when texture coordinates and vertex coordinates are not one-to-one correspondence, what will the rendering result turn out to be?

Comment: your question is unclear please write down rendering geometry code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there needs to be a one-to-one correspondence between vertices and texCoords -- all information passed down the OpenGL pipeline is per-vertex, so every normal and every texCoord must have a vertex.

Note, however, that you can (and will often need to) have multiple texCoords, normals, or other per-vertex data for the same point in space: e.g. if you're wrapping a texture map around a sphere, there will be a "seam" where the ends of the rectangular texture meet. At those spots you'll need to have multiple vertices that occupy the same point.